# Prettier tab symbols in vim

Tags: vim

I’m trying to make vim look more similar to what I’m used to in Coda 2.

In my `.vimrc` I have this line:

```
set listchars=tab:➝.,extends:#,nbsp:.
```

That makes my whitespace look like this:

[image]

However, I’d rather those dots weren’t visible, so it’d look more like this:

[image]

I've tried using a space character, but I end up with this warning:

```
E474: Invalid argument: listchars=tab:➝
```

What character can I use that won’t be visible on the screen, and also won’t throw a warning?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can escape the space character like this:

```
set listchars=tab:➝\ ,extends:#,nbsp:.
```

Answer (score 4):

In listchars `tab:` takes to characters. Directly from the help file:

```
  tab:xy    Two characters to be used to show a tab.  The first
        char is used once.  The second char is repeated to
        fill the space that the tab normally occupies.
        "tab:>-" will show a tab that takes four spaces as
        ">---".  When omitted, a tab is show as ^I.
```

So you can just use a space instead of the dot that you are using for the second character, it  does have to be escaped though: `set listchars=tab:➝\ ,extends:#,nbsp:.` to get the result you want.